# Change parent div size as child gets longer while having position:absolute in Angular2

Tags: css, angular

So the title is quite a mouth full, and I am struggling to get a exact answer for this on SO. I have a few child div's in a container div, that gets loaded with data form a database every time the page loads. Depending on the option chosen, the vertical size of the child div's change depending one the amount of information (No fixed size). But (due to the look and feel), I must have the child div's also overlapping and on-top of each other (using z-index), which means that the child div's all have the property of position:absolute. This means that as they expand, they just expand past the bottom edge of the parent container without "pushing" it along, or making it larger.

So I would like to know that the best way would be in Angular2 to get the size of the child div's, use the largest size, and set the parent height to this size (+ lets say 20px). Because it is Angular2 I don't just want to use jquery seeing as that is not the way to use Angular.

So I added my code to show what I have at the moment:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nlr-container-bottom-footer',
  template: `<div id="main">    
                <div id="boks3">
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                </div>
                <div id="boks2">
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                </div>
                <div id="boks4">
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                    * <br>
                </div>
            </div>`,
  styles: [`
    #main {
        background-color: yellow;
}
#boks2,
#boks3,
#boks4
       {
  background-color: red;
  width: 32%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 33.5%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: left;
}
#boks2 {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 17%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100px;
}
#boks4 {
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: right;
  height: 100px;
}
`],
})
export class ContainerBottomFooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

So as you can see it gives three boxes, two at the "bottom" and one on top of them. The fact that they have to be stacked, is also why they have to be "position:absolute". But as you can see the text in all three boxes just go past the height of the main container (or does not even effect it at all).
**So I am trying to find a way to get the height of the largest boks, and then pass that height on to the main container.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

**-- UPDATE # 2 --**

```
export class ContainerBottomFooterComponent {

 @ViewChildren('.plates', {read: ElementRef}) //Here we say "Go look at the children (there is more than one) classes called 'plates', it then looks like we are reading all the ElementReferences of those classes"
 public books: QueryList<ElementRef> //Here we are giving the variable "books" the list of off all the references of all the classes.
 @ViewChild('main', {read: ElementRef})// Here we are reading a single reference of the div with id "main"
 public mainContainerRef: ElementRef; // Here we are giving the variable mainContainerRef the element references of the div with ID class #main


   constructor( private _renderer:Renderer) {
        let height = this.books.reduce((height, bookRef) => {
        let rect = bookRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        return rect.height > height ? rect.height: height;
        }, 0);
    }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainContainerRef.nativeElement, 'height', height + 'px');
  } 

}
```

Comment: it's opinionated.

Comment: Hi Alfa, this site is not a show me how to do it site - it is for when you have attempted a piece of code and have got stuck on a specific problem.  In it's current form, your  question is off topic for the site as it is way too broad (ie there are too many possible answers to your problem)

Comment: Thank you, I understand. It is just so difficult with Angular2 to post your code because everything has so many dependencies and is so interwoven. Just thought someone may have a good suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ViewChildren Decorator:

```
@ViewChildren('.itsABook', {read: ElementRef}) 
public books: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChild('main', {read: ElementRef})
public mainContainerRef: ElementRef;
```

and then iterate over the QueryList:

```
let height = this.books.reduce((height, bookRef) => {
  let rect = bookRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  return rect.height > height ? rect.height: height;
}, 0);
```

and set the height of the main container using the `Renderer`:

```
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainContainerRef.nativeElement, 'height', height + 'px');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main" #main>
  <div class="itsABook"></div>
  <div class="itsABook"></div>
  <div class="itsABook"></div>
</div>
```

Also keep in mind that the references for `books` and `mainContainerRef` are only available after `ngAfterViewInit` hook

Edit: Added reference for mainContainer

Comment: Hi cyrix. Thank you for the answer. I do not understand half of it, but I am trying to implement it into my code. At the moment I still can not get the "mainContainerRef" to work. Can you please help and tell me what this would be in the example, then I can study it. Thank allot.

Comment: You can get the reference to your main container with: `@ViewChild(mainContainer, {red: ElementRef}) mainContainerRef: ElementRef` and adding `#mainContainer` to your div: `<div id="main" #main>` then using it with `this.mainContainerRef`

Comment: Hi cyrix, would the example still work if in the HTML my three div's have three different id's like in my code above, instead of one single class?

Comment: Sure you can keep your IDs and just add the class `<div id="books1" class="itsABook">`

Comment: Hi cyrix, so I have been busy with this until now, and have updated my code above to show what it looks like now. But I get an error "cannot find name height" on the `height + 'px'` bit. Have learned allot today but now I am exhausted...

Comment: Thank you cyrix, got it all sorted out now. You helped allot!!

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `(transitionend)="onSizeChanged()"` callback in my .html file and defined a transition like so `transition: width 1ms, height 1ms;` in my .scss which worked for me. In the adjustSize() method you can then set your desired width and height (presumably the dimensions of your absolute-positioned ViewChild) and bind the values in your parent div like so: `[style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height"`. When facing performance issues you can use a BehaviorSubject and subscribe to it, using auditTime() to debounce it.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent" [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height">
  <div #child class="child" (transitionend)="onSizeChanged()>
    /*this component can change in size*/
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  transition: width 1ms, height 1ms;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild('child') private child: ElementRef;

private _width = 0;
private _height = 0;

public get width(): number {
  return this._width;
}

public get height(): number {
  return this._height;
}

public onSizeChanged() {
  this._width = this.child.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
  this._height = this.child.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
}
```

I know this is sort of a hack, but it's not stupid if it works.